# Regex for SpecialCharacters in bewteen in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create regex which check if string has any special characters only in between. So I am checking for following cases:

> - "BX_@PO"  -- Invalid
> - "40-66-7" -- Invalid
> - "_BXTP"   -- Valid
> - "abc123?"   -- Valid
> - "BXTP@"   -- Valid
> - "PO@GO_"  -- Invalid

I am trying below code but it which check special characters in anywhere in string and not only in between.

```
const hasSpecialCharacters = (str) => {
    return !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
}
```

Comment: What are non-special characters? All alpha-numeric ASCII characters, i.e. a-z, A-Z and 0-9?

Comment: @Xufox - they all should be allowed in the string.

Comment: Could you please translate into real English *trying to create regex which check if string has any special characters only in between*? It is too obscure and allows various interpretations.

Comment: Something tells me you need [`/^[^\W_]*[\W_][^\W_]*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/1oHNGB/1). It is still guessing. It will match a string with only one special char or `_`.

Comment: So, does [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/1oHNGB/2) work correctly?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew that worked for me! Many thanks :)

Comment: But you marked Gurman's answer as correct - and our patterns are not the same. See [that answer](https://regex101.com/r/PC2n45/2) and [my regex differene](https://regex101.com/r/PC2n45/3). It is not clear what you need.

Comment: Well, your solution only covered what I mentioned in my question examples (with _ at the starting and end) and my question was any special characters in between ONLY in the input string. Your sol. was not wrong and to the point of my examples, but if I used any sp. char. at the end (apart from _) then your regex will reject that string. Hence, choose Gurman's answer as correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

`^[\s\S][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s\S]$`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bcFMSF/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `[\s\S]` - matches any character
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - matching 0+ occurrences of only letters and digits in the middle. Thus, not allowing special characters in the middle
- `[\s\S]` - matches any character
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Comment: Hi Gurman, thanks for your answer, If I have to add any whitelisting for valid special characters then how I can do it with your suggested approach. Like If I have to whitelist below characters:  "/ - ? : ( ) . , ' + SPACE"

Comment: @user7890278 you mean to say that you want to allow these characters in the middle?

Comment: In that case, use [`^[\s\S][a-zA-Z0-9 \/\-?:().,'+]*[\s\S]$`](https://regex101.com/r/bcFMSF/5). But, note that, in this case, `40-66-7` also becomes a valid scenario as you are allowing `-` in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Just like [T.J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829199/98493), but going for the readable way around:

```
const hasSpecialCharacters = (str) => {
  return !/[a-zA-Z0-9][^a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]/g.test(str)
}
```

Comment: Well, I assumed the OP's regex was specific for a reason. But I don't think it matches the examples of valid/invalid, so I moved on.

Comment: I think OP missed `@` in their character class, so it wasn't matching.